# Heroku: Suitable for a Real-Time Game Server?

Tags: heroku

I am trying to run a real-time game server on Heroku using Java/Netty. The game server uses a non-standard port for communication (4876/tcp). I have built the game client using Unity3D. The game client communicates with the game server using a binary protocol (i.e. it is not using HTTP).

Is it possible for me to host this on Heroku? Heroku looks like it can only host web apps on port 80 or 443 (i.e. the web process in the procfile).

To complicate things slightly I also have a web services app built using Java/Embedded Jetty which needs to be able to communicate with the game client and the real-time game server which I also want to host on Heroku. Is this possible because I know there can be no inter-process communication? What if I create two seperate apps (one fore web services and one for real-time game server) on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the time of this answer, heroku only supports http and hptts as you have noticed.

You could try modifying your game to use http as a transport for the binary protocol.

Comment: Thanks Will. It would take a lot of work to reimplement my protocol plus HTTP would be too slow/unnecessary overhead. Do you know another solution I can use that would let me run game server?